# Shared memory configuration for prefetching

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict

In my program I use shared memory to do prefetching of data. A 2D block of threads, dimentions 8 by 4 (32), gets `8 * 4 * 8 * sizeof(float4)` bytes of shared memory. Each thread copies 8 `float4`s in a loop:

```
inline __device__ void pack(const float4 *g_src, float4 *s_dst, const unsigned int w, const unsigned int d) {
    uint2 indx = { blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x, blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y };
    uint2 sindx = { threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < d; ++i) s_dst[(sindx.y * blockDim.x + sindx.x) * d + i] = g_src[(w * indx.y + indx.x) * d + i];
}
```

where `w` is set to width of the global memory buffer (in number of `float4`s) and `d` is set to 8 (number of `float4`s copied).

Can such configuration and further usage of the memory, lead to bank conflicts, or will broadcasting be applied? Will this be a case also when threads copy only, say 5 `float4`s, not 8?

MK

P.S.
Same topic [in Nvidia forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/532767/cuda-programming-and-performance/shared-memory-configuration/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During prefetching phase bank conflicts will occur. E.g. threads within first warp with IDs (computed as `threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x`) 0, 4, 8, ... 28 access same bank. You can see it as thread (0,0) and thread (4,0) for `i` equals 0 access `s_dst[0]` and `s_dst[32]` belonging to the same bank.

If bank conflicts occur during further usage depends on the scheme you will access `s_dst`.

Broadcast mechanism is applied only when threads simultaneously **read** the same address.

How many bank conflicts occur depends on the value of `d`. If `d mod 32 == 1` there won't be any conflicts.

**EDIT:**
IMHO the best way to avoid bank conflicts in prefetching phase, specially if `d` is changing, is to equaly split the work among the warps. Lets say you need to prefetch `n` values to shared memory, `w_id` is ID of warp and `l_id` is ID of thread within warp (from 0 to 31). Than prefetching should look like this:

```
for(int i = l_id + w_id*WARP_SIZE; i < n; i += WARP_SIZE*COUNT_OF_WARPS_IN_BLOCK)
{
    s_dst[i] = ...;
}
```

But this helps only to avoid bank conflicts during prefetching. As I have already said to avoid conflicts during further usage depends on the scheme you will access `s_dst`.

Comment: Can it be done without bank conflicts? Would unrolling the 'for' loop do better?

Comment: w_id = (threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) / 32, l_id = (threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) % 32

Comment: `n` is equal to entire count of values that are going to be prefetched.

Comment: And how, according to this, address global memory?

Comment: You have to add some offset to `i` determined by ID of block which represents beginning of data in global memory belonging to that block. Something like `g_src[BLOCK_ID * n + i]`